# How do you translate 'positions of a value 2' into a mathematical notation when defining a bijection?

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Let's say I have a multi-set: $(1,1,2)$
And I want to define a bijection from $A$ to $B$ such that:

$(1,1,2)$ becomes {3} and,

$(1,1,1)$ becomes {} and,

$(2,2,2)$ becomes {1,2,3} or,

in general, it is a set of the positions of $2$ in $A$.

So the rough idea of f is as below:
f( (n_1, ... , n_some_number) ) = {"positions of 2 from n_i"}

But I am not so confident in defining this function in mathematical notion. So I would love to hear some advice.

Let me know if my question makes sense, I will add more info accordingly!

Comment: Question: Does (1,1,2) = (1,2,1)? Because if so, then it's impossible.

Comment: you're assuming B is well defined, which it isn't. In order to define B you need to be able to say (1,1,2) is different to (1,2,1), I.e (1,1,2) $\neq$ (1,2,1)

Comment: What you need to do is define B using another object like an Multi-Set but that has a concept of ordering for it's elements.

Comment: What you need to do is define B using another object like an Multi-Set but that has a concept of ordering for it's elements.

Comment: Here's an analogy: Can you define a function $f$ which given a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ returns $a + b$? No it's impossible. But you can define $f$ to return $a + b$ given an irreducible rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a \geq 0$.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, I'm telling you that it's impossible. Specifically it is mathematically impossible to define your function that maps values of A to values of B, given the condition that A is a multiset. That is why I said you must modify your function to take a different object as input, something like multisets but with a concept of order for its elements. Only then is it possible. If you don't see why, refer to my analogy with a function that returns $a+b$ of $\frac{a}{b}$ above. That example is more clear and simple, but fundamentally the same problem.

Comment: Brian M. Scott wrote an answer below where he proposes defining your function using finite sequences instead of multisets. That's one approach, does it make sense to you?

Comment: Try this for me, you say (1,1,2) and {1,1,2} are different? Ok I know how they are different, don't tell me how, just tell me which one is a multi-set under whatever definition of a multi-set you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Multisets are not ordered, so this does not really make sense. You can, however, define a function from the set of finite **sequences** of positive integers to the set of finite sets of positive integers that sends $\langle n_1,\ldots,n_m\rangle$ to $\{k\in[m]:n_k=2\}$, where as usual $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$. If you’re considering only $m$-tuples for some fixed $m$, then each will be sent to a subset of $[m]$, but the map is not injective and hence not a bijection.